# How can I reject files named '!' with wget?

Tags: regex, shell, wget

I'm using `wget` to recursively download my university's pages for later analysis and am filtering **lots** of extensions.
Here's a mwe with the relevant function:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

unwanted_extensions='*.apk,*.asc,*.asp,*.avi,*.bat,*.bib,*.bmp,*.bz2,*.c,*.cdf,*.cgi,*.class,*.cpp,*.crt,*.csp,*.css,*.cur,*.dat,*.dll,*.dvi,*.dwg,*.eot,*.eps,*.epub,*.exe,*.f,*.flv,*.for,*.ggb,*.gif,*.gpx,*.gz,*.h,*.heic,*.hpp,*.hqx,*.htc,*.ico,*.jfif,*.jpe,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.js,*.lib,*.lnk,*.ly,*.m,*.m4a,*.m4v,*.mdb,*.mht,*.mid,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.mpeg,*.mpg,*.mso,*.odb,*.ogv,*.otf,*.out,*.pdb,*.pdf,*.php,*.plot,*.png,*.ps,*.psz,*.py,*.rar,*.sav,*.sf3,*.sgp,*.sh,*.sib,*.svg,*.swf,*.tex,*.tgz,*.tif,*.tiff,*.tmp,*.ttf,*.txt,*.wav,*.webm,*.webmanifest,*.webp,*.wmf,*.woff,*.woff2,*.wxm,*.wxmx,*.xbm,*.xml,*.xps,*.zip'
unwanted_regex='/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'

wget_custom ()
{
    link="$1"
    wget \
        --recursive -e robots=off --level=inf --quiet \
        --ignore-case --adjust-extension --convert-file-only \
        --reject "$unwanted_extensions" \
        --reject-regex "$unwanted_regex" --regex-type posix \
        "$link"
}

wget_custom "$1"
```

It works nicely and filters most of the stuff. However, these webs serve many pdf and image files named `!` (e.g. `biologiacelular.ugr.es/pages/planoweb/!`) which I don't need and want to reject. Here's what i've tried but hasn't worked:

- Appending `,!` to `unwanted_extensions`
- Appending `,%21` to `unwanted_extensions`
- Changing `unwanted_regex` to `'/([a-zA-Z0-9!]+)$'`
- Changing `unwanted_regex` to `'/([a-zA-Z0-9\!]+)$'`
- Adding nother `--reject-regex '/!$`
- Adding nother `--reject-regex '/\!$`

None of these work and I'm out of ideas. How can I filter the `!` files? Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't that unwanted regex filter everything that consists of just characters and digits? And the wget manual isn't clear about this, is `posix` BRE or ERE? If the former, with extensions, you'd need `\+`, and without extensions, something like `\{1,\}` instead of `+`.

Comment: That regex filters files without extension, @BenjaminW.m which I don't need because they're not the one's I'm looking for. But that's not the point, that regex's working fine as it is. What I'm trying to filter are files named `!` like the one in the example (`biologiacelular.ugr.es/pages/planoweb/!`).

Comment: The last 4 should work in my opinion just in terms of regular expressions matching `/!`, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work, I'm afraid.